# Activity not required for Android app running in the background

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-service

The error occurred within Visual studio when running an Xamarin Android app that doesn't require Activity and runs in background.

> No Launchable Activity: This project does not contain any activities
> marked MainLauncher. It has been deployed to the device, but no
> activity will be launched.
>
> To mark an activity as launchable, add the [Activity] attribute to it
> with MainLauncher = true:
>
> [Activity (MainLauncher = true)]   public class MyActivity : Activity

Below is my code

```
[Application(Label = "@string/app_name")]
    public class Application : Android.App.Application
    {
        public Application(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
           : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this);      
            Intent oaServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainApplicationService));
            StartService(oaServiceIntent);
        }
}
```

Do I have to create an Activity even it is not required?

Comment: Based my research, you need to create a Activity as a `MainLauncher =true`, then you can open a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the user to launch your app, you must have at least one `Activity` and it must have an entry in the manifest with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER so that it will show up on the HOME screen.

If the user cannot manually launch your app then it cannot be started and no background components (`Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.) will run.

The `Application` instance is only created when Android creates an OS process to host your app and this will only happen if the user has manually launched your app **at least once** after installation.